Выделение видео конференции в отдельное окно
Сервис meet.google позволяет выносить все свое окно в отдельное мини-окно. Погуглив, я узнал, что браузер Chrome предоставляет WebAPI documentPictureInPicture, который дает так сделать.
Проблема возникла в браузере Opera GX. Он тоже предоставляет возможность выноса окна видеоконференции, но не поддерживает documentPictureInPicture.
Как мне для своей страницы сделать такую же функцию? Если с хромом все понятно, то как быть с GX? Я же вижу, что функционал есть, но как получить к нему доступ? (Достаточно ссылки на документацию)
Примечание: трансляция в video элемент содержимого страницы и его вывод мне не подходят. Это даже близко не похоже на то, что делает meet.google
Иконка на скрине кликабельна. Можешь создать конференцию и в Opera GX нажать на неё.

